# How to convert a date YYYY-MM-DD to epoch in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, epoch

As per title: how to convert a string date (YYYY-MM-DD) to epoch (seconds since 01-01-1970) in PHP

Comment: Did you try to search on SO before asking your question? There is a lot of questions related to this topic. Here is on: [mm/dd/yyyy format to epoch with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359782/mm-dd-yyyy-format-to-epoch-with-php)

Comment: the worse is all the people using unnecessary acronyms and making unnecessary comments: what's SO? maybe did you mean SE (Search Engine), didn't u?

Comment: SO means StackOverflow, sorry. SE could mean StackExchange network. Meta means meta.stackoverflow.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Perhaps this answers your question

http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/functions-php.php

Here is the content of the link:

There are many options:

1. Using 'strtotime':

strtotime parses most English language date texts to epoch/Unix Time.

```
echo strtotime("15 November 2012");
// ... or ...
echo strtotime("2012/11/15");
// ... or ...
echo strtotime("+10 days"); // 10 days from now
```

It's important to check if the conversion was successful:

```
// PHP 5.1.0 or higher, earlier versions check: strtotime($string)) === -1
if ((strtotime("this is no date")) === false) {
   echo 'failed';
 }
```

2. Using the DateTime class:

The PHP 5 DateTime class is nicer to use:

```
// object oriented
$date = new DateTime('01/15/2010'); // format: MM/DD/YYYY
echo $date->format('U'); 

// or procedural
$date = date_create('01/15/2010'); 
echo date_format($date, 'U');
```

The date format 'U' converts the date to a UNIX timestamp.

3. Using 'mktime':

This version is more of a hassle but works on any PHP version.

```
// PHP 5.1+ 
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  // optional 
mktime ( $hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year );

// before PHP 5.1
mktime ( $hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year, $is_dst );
// $is_dst : 1 = daylight savings time (DST), 0 = no DST ,  -1 (default) = auto

// example: generate epoch for Jan 1, 2000 (all PHP versions)
echo mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2000);
```

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry j0k won't happen again :)

Answer (score 13):

Try this :

```
$date  = '2013-03-13';

$dt   = new DateTime($date);
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: Interesting tidbit about this answer. It works only for dates past the UNIX epoch. Not that many people need earlier times, but it will not output a negative.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) function:

```
strtotime('2013-03-13');
```

Answer (score 3):

use `strtotime()` it provides you Unix time stamp starting from 01-01-1970